# RavenDB: If I'm creating an index with Ids, should I specify any index options?

Tags: indexing, ravendb, lucene

From [RavenDB's documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/configuring-index-options):

> The indexes each RavenDB server instance uses to facilitate fast
>   queries are powered by **Lucene**, the full-text search engine.
>
> Lucene takes a Document , breaks it down into Fields , and then splits
>   all text in a Field into tokens ( Terms ) in a process called
>   Tokenization . Those tokens are what will be stored in the index, and
>   be later searched upon.
>
> {...}
>
> After the tokenization and analysis process is complete, the resulting
>   tokens are stored in an index, which is now ready to be search with.
>
> {...}
>
> The default values for each field are FieldStorage.No in Stores and
>   FieldIndexing.Default in Indexes.
>
> Setting FieldIndexing.No causes values to not be available in where
>   clauses when querying (similarly to not being present in the original
>   projection). **FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed causes whole properties to be
>   treated as a single token and matches must be exact, similarly to
>   using a KeywordAnalyzer on this field. The latter is useful for
>   product Ids, for example.** FieldIndexing.Analyzed allows to perform
>   full text search operations against the field. **FieldIndexing.Default
>   will index the field as a single term, in lower case.**

---

As I understand it, to create a RavenDB index, you simply need to specify the `Map` propertly, like the following:

```
public class PlayersIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Player>
{
    public PlayersIndex()
    {
        Map = players => from doc in players
                            select new { doc.PlayerId, doc.TeamId, doc.PositionId };
    }
}
```

Here is my question:

If you assume that `PlayerId` is a `Guid`, `TeamId` is an `int`, and `PositionId` is an `enum`, should I:

1. Refrain from specifying any indexing options?
2. Configure each field as `FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed`?

In other words, should I entertain the idea of specifying the fields like the following?

```
public class PlayersIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Player>
{
    public PlayersIndex()
    {
        Map = players => from doc in players
                            select new { doc.PlayerId, doc.TeamId, doc.PositionId };

        Indexes.Add(x => x.PlayerId, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
        Indexes.Add(x => x.TeamId, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
        Indexes.Add(x => x.PositionId, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim,
For your needs, you aren't going to have to specify any indexing options.

Comment: Ayende, does the indexing performance increase if the index fields are NotAnalyzed as opposed to the default of using the LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer? If so, is the increase completely negligible?